# Geolocation route using Route53, S3, CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53, forward, amazon-cloudfront

I am using S3, CloudFront and Route53 for web site hosting on AWS. I need to redirect specific uri using geolocation detection within my S3 bucket.

```
S3 Bucket
    en/
      - index.html

    de/
      - index.html
```

for example when someone requesting from Germany I want to redirect de/index.html
and for all others just to be default /en/index.html

Please help if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

When a user requests your content, CloudFront typically serves the requested content regardless of where the user is located. If you need to prevent users in specific countries from accessing your content, you can use the CloudFront geo restriction feature to do one of the following:

Allow your users to access your content only if they're in one of the countries on a whitelist of approved countries.
Prevent your users from accessing your content if they're in one of the countries on a blacklist of banned countries.

For example, if a request comes from a country where, for copyright reasons, you are not authorized to distribute your content, you can use CloudFront geo restriction to block the request.